# Had had before+verb..(grammar)

Tags: grammar

Let's say your storytelling about the one that got away kind of thing (hehe).

> I **hadn't had** the chance to say I like her **before** we got separated.

Is this grammatical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is grammatically correct according to the scenario.

> had had = was having. Please check this link [had had usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2658/what-does-had-had-mean-how-does-this-differ-from-had) from our partner Site.

You also try saying, `"I did not have the chance ..."`

or even `"I never had the chance ..`